# fulltext search with mysql FT or Sphinx

Tags: mysql, solr, sphinx

I have read many articles about Sphinx or Solr or MySQL FT.
I have a table with over 1 milion products and need to make an fulltext search and get results under 1 second ... . Does anyone has any experience with those kind of fast search? As clint language I am using PHP.

As capacity I have debian5 8GB ram 4 core cpu's.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing a stand-alone full-text search server: Sphinx or SOLR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284083/choosing-a-stand-alone-full-text-search-server-sphinx-or-solr)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728040/solr-or-sphinx-which-is-better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498046/sphinx-solr-lucene-elastic-relevancy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271600/elasticsearch-sphinx-lucene-solr-xapian-which-fits-for-which-usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903566/search-engine-solr-sphinx-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've made some Sphinx performance measurements that are described here http://www.ivinco.com/blog/plain-rt-and-mixed-indexes-performance-comparison/
As it can be seen searching in 1M dataset can be as fast as less than 0.1 sec per query. So I suggest you to use Sphinx.